# I'm developing my web app locally (file://) and icons from CDN don't show up

Tags: font-awesome

Im not sure whats happening, the font-aweseome file was loaded successfully as the developer console shows, but icons are not rendering at all. I only see a rectangle.

This is how I load font-awesome:

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Call:

```
<i class="fas fa-plus fa-5x"></i>
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your link to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css"
    integrity="sha384-+d0P83n9kaQMCwj8F4RJB66tzIwOKmrdb46+porD/OvrJ+37WqIM7UoBtwHO6Nlg"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: This worked, my netbeans IDE spits `Attribute "integrity" not allowed on element "link" at this point"` though, but I will ignore it. I can accept answer in 10 minutes.